# ASP Net core - How to implement background services localization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service, asp.net-core-localization

In posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484503/cpu-memory-usage-thread-pool-usage-asp-net-core-identity-not-confirmed-mail) a question asking about best implementation of deleting inactive users in ASP NET core app. Ian Kemp suggested background service for that and I really liked this.

Now I'm wondering how to implement localizer into background service (I need to notify them that soon their account will be deleted)? I can store information about cultrue which user is using when browsing my app. I saw a function for *IStringLocalizer< SomeClass >* - *WithCulture* which returns a new IStringLocalizer with requested culture. But it shows it is deprecated. Is there any other way how to implement Localizer to background service (while using stored culture of user in DB)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "localizer" but if you want to return a localized message you could use a resource file (.resx extension) and maintain a resource per culture. You can pull from the correct file based on the thread culture or you can use the static code behind and pass a CultureInfo instance.

Comment: I use resx files, in ASP NET core there's a class IStringLocalizer<Class> which takes care about localized strings based on keys sent to the instance. Localizer is instance.
Localizer["MyLocalizedString"] returns localized string from resx files based on HttpRequest culture. But in Background service, there's no HttpRequest culture so  I'm wondering how to 'say' to IStringLocalizer (or any suggested Localizer) that I want a certain culture.
Plus I saw the WithCulture is deprecated so I'm looking for a different option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have language code then you can set the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to get the localized string via `stringLocalizer`.

```
    public class ResourceProvider
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer;
        public ResourceProvider(IStringLocalizerFactory localizerFactory)
        {
            stringLocalizer = localizerFactory.Create("ResourceStrings", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        }

        public string GetLocalizedString(string resourceKey, string languageCode)
        {
          CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageCode);
          var localizedString = stringLocalizer[resourceKey].Value;
          return localizedString;
        }
    }
```